# Python - pass a class object as parameter to a function

Tags: python

I have a class, for example :

```
class Exam:
    def __init__(self, exam_date='', exam_semester=''):
        self.exam_date = exam_date
        self.exam_semester = exam_semester
```

And I need to get the date & semester info from a text file, so I have the following function in a different .py file (which imports my class.py file):

```
def get_exam_info(obj):
    with open('Exams.txt') as f:
        line = f.read().split()
    obj.exam_date = line[0]
    obj.exam_semester = line[1]
```

now my question is, how I make (if needed to make at all) the `get_exam_info` function to recognize `obj` as an object of type `Exam`, like in c++ you would have:

```
void myFunction(Exam *obj) {}
```

so I would have access to my fields `self.exam_date` & `self.exam_semester` (by access I mean that it will automatically complete me when I do obj. action like in c++)

**I know it easier to implement this as a class method**, it's just I was asked to do it in a different file.

Comment: You don't need to do anything like this. Python is a dynamically-typed language, you don't need to declare types.

Comment: You cannot create an `Exam` object without giving it date and semester values, so it makes no sense to pass one in to this function.  Instead, create one in the function and return it: `return Exam(line[0], line[1])`.

Comment: @jasonharper I have a driver main file where I create the object with has default values with the constructor, after its created I need to pass it so I can insert the values from the file in to the class fields.

Comment: @Iguananaut it's a class assignment where we choose the language we program with.

Comment: Fair enough, though you might impress your professor anyways by taking a different approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [typing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/typing.html) which was introduced in Python 3.5. I hope it is a feature you look for.